# How to close x number of popups one by one according to their visiblity?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

Lets suppose, there are 4 popups in my application and a viewer presses Escape once. Now i want application to close the popup which is on the top. I dont know how to accompish this because i dont know thich popup is to the front right now.

Regards
Max

Comment: When you say "Popup" do you mean something you created with the PopUpManager or something else?  When they hit escape, wouldn't you just close the PopUp which has the current focus?  Which in theory will be the one that is on top.

Comment: ESC will do that but it won't give focus to the next window.

If you are using PopUpManager, although I am not entirely sure, I think it keeps track of the windows it has open and which are in front of which. Again, not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Flextras, I'm using PopupManager to create popups, sorry for my little knowledge but i'm not sure how to close the popup which is in focus.

Comment: @Francisc, Yup i want to close and then shift focus to next top/front popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the children in the systemmanager to know what child is on top. The last child will always be the top one. If you re-order windows, the collection will be updated. At least that is what a quick test tells me.

```
var sm:ISystemManager = Application.application.systemManager;
var topChildIndex:int = sm.numChildren - 1;
var topChild:Object = sm.getChildAt(topChildIndex);
// do something with topChild
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out and let you know tonight